# Why is "if "statement is causing "While True:" Loop to cease operation

Tags: python-3.x

I have a "while True:" loop in python 3 that is taking some serial data from a com port and processing it. The stream of data needs a serial write to continue sending data if a specific string of bytes is read from the port. Once the stream of bytes is found and the serial write is executed, the "while True:" stops running. I think it has something to do with an input from a keyboard.

To troubleshoot, I inserted some code to manually enter the serial write, it works and then continues to read and process data. Can someone explain why the "while True:" loop ceases to run and how to fix it with a command that does not involve the keyboard?

Here is the code:

```
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=0) 
    print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
    while True:
        try:
            the_date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            # Read line from serial port in bytes 
            s = ser.readline()        
            #convert to utf-8 for use in serial operations 
            s_text_in = s.decode('utf_8')
            if(s_text_in.find(com_strt_string) != -1):

                print("found the specific string")
                #all_logs_str = input("What is your name? ")
                #type(all_logs_str)
                all_logs_str = 'Send Data\r'
                all_logs_str_bytes = all_logs_str.encode('utf-8', "ignore")
                ser.write(all_logs_str.encode())

            else:
                print("skipped")
                continue


            info_type = port_interpreter(s_text_in)
            print(s_text_in)

            if(info_type == 1):
                s_text = num_remover(s_text_in)
                err_fl.write(the_date + ' ' + s_text + '\n')
                print("wrote E")
            elif(info_type == 2):
                s_text = num_remover(s_text_in)
                war_fl.write(the_date + ' ' + s_text + '\n')
                print("wrote W")
            else:
                s_text = num_remover(s_text_in)
                info_fl.write(the_date + ' ' + s_text + '\n')
                print("wrote I")


        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Stopping flow of infinite loop. 
            print("[CTRL+C detected]")  
            err_fl.close()
            war_fl.close()
            info_fl.close()
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Otherwise it sides like it isn't exiting the loop but instead stuck somewhere. Can you paste the output of your print statements when you run it?

Comment: No errors are thrown. It just ceases to run. I think there is a thread running that expects some sort of input from the keyboard to continue. If you look at the commented lines where the input is, that will cause it to work

Comment: Uncommenting `input("What is your name? ")` will make it work you said?

Comment: Correct, But I need this to work without keyboard inputs. It's running in the background of a GUI. Thanks.

Comment: So does it never hit `print(s_text_in)` without that input?

Comment: It ran all the way to the bottom and paused before the "Except" statement. So I concluded that the "While True:" somehow became false.

Comment: Add more prints to figure out exactly where is stopped (including a print at the top of the loop). Then add the output of those prints to your question.

Comment: From what I found,  The Ubuntu laptop I was using had a thread going that was blocked and waiting for a keyboard input. I used "pyautogui" to create one simple keyboard button pushed and it worked. This is my theory. I don't know how to confirm this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved using pyautogui. The Ubuntu python3.6  idle thread was looking for some (any) keyboard input as the thread was paused. as soon as keyboard input was detected, it resumed. I am not sure why this occurred but that fixed the issue.